# Show full list of nodes that reference the node being shown

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type (let's call it course) and a content type named edition (if we have a course named "English 101", we can have "English 101 - June", "English 101 - July" and so on.) For this, I used Entity Reference.

If I see the node "English 101-June", I can see the "*parent*" node being rendered (I chose that on Manage Display". What I want now, is when I see the "*parent*" node "English 101" the full list of referenced nodes to be rendered. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to get reverse references. Probably the best option is to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. The [reference module](http://drupal.org/project/references) allows to create a reverse relationship in the view. You could do something like this:

- With the Views module, create a view of nodes with a page display at path 'myview' ;
- Set up your view to display only the title of each node ;
- In your view add an argument that matches your node id ;
- In your view add a reverse relationship that matches the field that is used to reference content. The name to use for the relationship would be something like `field_my_reference_field (reverse)`

Save the view, now go to 'myview/1' and you will see all the nodes that reference node 1. You could also get this displayed in a block, or as a field using the [ViewField module](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield).

If you don't want to use the Views module, then you can use the [Nodereferrer module](http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer) to achieve this. However in that case you can only get the list as a field - you can't get it as page or a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a first view to list all your courses nodes.

And next, in a custom module, you display the references  (with antoher view who accept an argument of the parent reference nid)

```
function custommodule_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  list($id, $rev, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($type, $entity);
  switch ($bundle){
  case 'course':
    if( $view_mode == 'full' ){
      $entity->children['children'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<h1>Childrens</h1>'. views_embed_view( 'childrens', 'default', $entity->field_course['und'][0]['nid'] ),
      );
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well. What I want is to list the nodes when I am viewing the "parent" node, not a list with all nodes and the references

Comment: you can add a condition to display only if the node is in full page : if( preg_match('#^node/.*#', $_GET['q'], $matches) );